# Find a matching value in date range and return value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a solution where I want to find a price that was valid at a specific time range and insert the result in a transaction table.
The price table only have a date stamp when the price was updated and price changes creates a new row with a new date.

I have joined the two tables together but my attempts only results in multiple extra rows created.

```
 SELECT t.ID
,t.Date
,t.ArtNo
,t.SellPrice
,p.Price

FROM TRANS t

LEFT JOIN Price p ON p.ArtNo = t.ArtNo AND p.Date <=t.Date
```

Desired outcome:

```
ID  Date                ArtNo   SellPrice  Price
1   17/08/2016 00:00:00 A1010   30         21.8
2   02/04/2017 00:00:00 A1010   31         21.8
3   01/03/2018 00:00:00 A1010   31         22.35
4   01/11/2016 00:00:00 B2000   5          4.1
5   30/05/2017 00:00:00 B2000   5          4.17
6   29/10/2017 00:00:00 B2000   5          4.17
```

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88cecdf5823dad2f0d2c369ef4decf43)

Comment: Thank you all for you contributions, all 3 solutions work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
          t.ID
        , t.Date
        , t.ArtNo
        , t.SellPrice
        , pr.Price

FROM TRANS t
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP (1) p.Price
              FROM Price p 
              WHERE p.ArtNo = t.ArtNo 
                AND p.Date <=t.Date
              ORDER BY p.Date DESC
            ) pr(Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CROSS APPLY To get the desired results like below

```
SELECT t.ID
,t.Date
,t.ArtNo
,t.SellPrice
,p.Price

FROM TRANS t
Cross apply
(
select *, r1=row_number() over (partition by ArtNo order by Date desc)
from Price P 
 where p.Date <=t.Date and p.ArtNo=t.ArtNo
)p
where p.r1 =1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple query with subquery:

```
select ID,
       [Date],
       ArtNo,
       SellPrice,
       (select Price from price p where p.ArtNo = t.ArtNo and p.[Date] = (select max([date]) from Price p2 where t.ArtNo = p2.ArtNo and p2.[Date] <= t.[Date])) [Price]
from TRANS t
```

Comment: He does not want the max(price) but the the price on nearest date. You could write that as: SELECT 
          t.ID
        , t.Date
        , t.ArtNo
        , t.SellPrice
        , (select Price 
           from price p 
           where p.ArtNo = t.ArtNo and p.[Date] = 
             (select max([date]) from Price p2 where t.ArtNo = p2.ArtNo and p2.[Date] <= t.[Date] )) as Price
FROM TRANS t

Comment: @CetinBasoz No, I don't agree. OP states explicitly in query, that the date sholud be lower: `p.Date <=t.Date`, thus, `MAX(Date)` will return closest date, which is lower.

Comment: Exactly and that is what I meant (nearest ın past I should say). You have max(Price) not date.

Comment: @CetinBasoz You are totally right... I don't know how I could make mistake like that :O. Thanks for being cautious.

Comment: Happens to us all :)